# Contact form node integration

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, emails

I have content type and I want to add contact button at the bottom of node page, but

I've problem so how I can add easy contact form that add node title at the message and When anonymous user goes node page called "Example 12" and after body text there is "Contact" or "Ask more" button and it goes form page.

After user left the message it goes admin content list and admins knows page where he/she goes that contact form.

Example I check page named "Example12" and there is ask more button.. I press that and I goes Ask more form and there is some fields and "You want to know more about example12" (example12 page title) and then I send that and it goes admin content list page so admins can contact me because I left mail in mail field.

So what is the best way to do it? Is there any good modules for that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a case for the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module.

> Webform is the module for making forms and surveys in Drupal. After a
>   submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a
>   notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or
>   other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic
>   statistical review and has an extensive API for expanding its
>   features. Some good examples could be contests, personalized contact
>   forms, or petitions.

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform